# Css align div one line

Tags: html, css

I trying to align [this code](http://fiddle.jshell.net/x4287s1a/)
to get something like [image]

how to write right syntax, to do right peace of code showing in picture, align to look like in picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an [updated Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/nrdLy3L0/3/) that gets you a little closer to what you need. So what did I do?

- First, your HTML needs a lot of cleaning up. I did a small amount, but I would suggest that you spend some time going through it, indenting things correctly, and breaking it into logical sections.
- For the right hand side, I broke each row into its own `div` to logically separate them. This makes it easier to style consistently.
- The controls in each row were given fixed pixel widths to help with alignment. A bit of a hack, but in this case it works.

@starikovs suggests using Flexbox, which is something you should research further. I would also suggest you spend some time learning about how to structure your HTML cleanly first. The fiddle I linked to here is only a quick cleanup!

**Edit**
In the interests of keeping everything in one place, I've copied the code here:

**HTML**

```
<form id=fbid26588961 name=fbid26588961> 
    <div class="full-info_auction-operations">
        <div class="full-info_auction-buy">
            <div class="auction-value">
                BuyNow
                <span>5394&nbsp;&euro;</span>
            </div>
            <input disabled id=buynow1 onclick="newcmd('cmd.asp?op=buynow&carid=26588961');" type=button value="BuyNow">
        </div>


        <div class="full-info_auction-raise">
            <div class="auction-value">
                Current Price
                <span>900&nbsp;&euro;</span>
            </div>
            <input type=button style="font-size:10px;" value="+100" onclick="pliusZZ(100);">
            <input type=button style="font-size:10px;" value="+200" onclick="pliusZZ(200);">
            <input type=button style="font-size:10px;" value="+500" onclick="pliusZZ(500);">
        </div>
        <div class="full-info_auction-confirm">
            <div class="auction-value">
                Your Bid

                <div class="ctrl_row">
                    <input placeholder="1000&nbsp;&euro;" class="robot i12" id=sumbid26588961>
                    <input type=checkbox onclick="fbid26588961.pbtn.disabled=!this.checked;" >
                    <input disabled name=pbtn onclick="placebid26588961();" type=button class="confirm-button" value="Confirm" />
                </div>

                <label class="confirm-raise">
                    <input placeholder="for bot" class="robot confirm-modify i12" />
                    <input class="checkbox-controller" type="checkbox" name="country" onclick="fbid26588961.rbtn.disabled=!this.checked;if(!this.checked){disablerobot26588961();}"  />
                    <input onclick="enablerobot26588961();" name=rbtn type=button  disabled  value="Enable robot">
                    <div class="checkbox"></div><span><div style="color:red">Robot disabled</div></span>
                </label>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
/* ORIGINAL CSS */
input[type="button"] {background: #5267ff; border-radius: 3px; border: none; font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; font-weight: 700; font-size: 11px; padding: 10px 14px; text-transform: uppercase;color:inherit;}
input[type="button"]:hover {background: #4758d2;}
.full-info_auction-operations {margin: 0 40px 0 85px; padding-top: 17px;}
.full-info_auction-operations input[type="button"] {display: inline-block; /*vertical-align: bottom;*/}
.full-info_auction-buy {max-width: 235px; display: inline-block; margin-right: 5px; padding: 5px 0 10px;}
.full-info_auction-operations.auction-value {font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #b1b1b1; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; text-align: left; line-height: 20px;margin: 0px 7px 0 0;}
.full-info_auction-operations.auction-value span {font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; font-weight: 700; font-size: 16px; color: #000; display: block;}
.full-info_auction-raise {max-width: 265px; display: inline-block; border-left: 1px solid #e7e7e8; border-right: 1px solid #e7e7e8; padding: 5px 10px 10px;}
//.full-info_auction-raise input[type="button"] {padding: 10px 11px 10px 10px; background: #000;}
.full-info_auction-confirm {max-width: 215px; display: inline-block; margin-left: 5px; padding: 5px 0 10px;}
.full-info_auction-confirm .auction-value {margin-right: 7px;}
.full-info_auction-operations > div {
   vertical-align: top;
}

/* NEW CSS BELOW */

.auction-value { float: left; font-size: 80%; color: #888; margin-right: 5px; }
.auction-value span { display: block; color: #000; }
.full-info_auction-buy input[type='button'] { color: #fff; }

.full-info_auction-raise input[type='button'] { background: #000; color: #fff; }

.robot { width: 50px; }
.ctrl_row { margin-bottom: 5px; }
.ctrl_row input[type='button'],
.confirm-raise  input[type='button'] { width: 120px; }
.confirm-modify { color: #fff; }
```

Comment: My code do a profesional design makers ))) So i now must change everything. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You only have to add `vertical-align: top;` than it should work.

Answer (score 2):

There you go :

```
.full-info_auction-operations > div {
   vertical-align: top;
}
```

This should do the job. @Mario Kurzweil answer was the good one, don't know why it's downvoted.

Comment: Why I don't want to help? I look at your example in jsfiddle and I give you a quick solution. If I don't want to help than I won't be here :).

Comment: It should be `.full-info_auction-operations > div ` (missing the period)

Comment: Works for me, just copy & paste it (with period) at the end of your CSS.

Comment: I am. The CSS in this answer (and Mario's) aligns everything to the top. It doesn't go into the rest of the details (text beside buttons, font sizes, etc), but it's a start!

Comment: It work's http://fiddle.jshell.net/xcbt3otv/2/

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin: Try [this fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/nrdLy3L0/1/). It's not complete, but then again, you can't expect us to do everything for you! :-)

Comment: Thanks! but for me is most important to do right peace of code align showing in picture

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin: Here's an [updated fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/nrdLy3L0/3/). Again, needs a bit of tidying up, but hopefully put you on the right track.

Comment: Wow thanks,that realy what i need!!! Write an answer i will accept

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin: Done, thanks!

Comment: Guys, you are commenting an answer, not the question. If you want to improve an answer or got a better answer, feel free to post your own solution.

Comment: @enguerranws: You're right, sorry about that, got carried away...

Answer (score 2):

The new way of doing that is to use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/infous/32ftoawr/):

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
}
```

That's all the styles you need.

1. BTW, you can use [Autoprefixer](http://autoprefixer.github.io) to get the right browser prefixes.
2. Flexbox is supported by all the major browsers: http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion this **[Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ah09urbL/1/)** comes to your desired layout very close. My added CSS is placed at the end (start is marked with a `/* */` ).

**CSS** I've added

```
.auction-value {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    color: #CCC;
    padding: 0 5px;
}
.auction-value > span {
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000;
}
.full-info_auction-confirm {
    max-width: 420px;
}
.auction-value > input {
    display: inline-block;
}
.bot-container {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.bot-container > label > * {
    display: inline-block;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
}
:-moz-placeholder {
    /* Firefox 18- */
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
}
::-moz-placeholder {
    /* Firefox 19+ */
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```